# Replace null to zero (query)

Tags: sql

In my table, there are 6 columns,

```
Id| Car Plate| Username| Color| Year| Rent|
```

The last column, the data type is bit but the value is null. How to convert null to 0 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS, it could be `ISNULL` or `IFNULL`

Comment: Do you want to actually **update** the records in the database, or do you want to leave them as NULL in the tables, but in your select query, retrieve a zero value if the underlying value is null?

Comment: Look for the `coalesce` function in your DBMS manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This query is for T-SQL:

```
UPDATE [yourTableName]
SET Rent = 0
WHERE Rent IS NULL
```

This will set the Rent column to 0 for all columns where rent is NULL.

Comment: Did he actually say he wanted to update the records, or just convert it in his select query?

Comment: The OP didn't indicate either way, so at this point I'd say both of us have valid solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which Database System, you can use [IsNull](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx&ei=9XhPUMSnG-KxywGNnIFg&usg=AFQjCNEJz08_K6gcpUoI1jPSlAa9ncPOAQ) or [COALESCE](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx&ei=BXlPUJrAEOPnyAGF6oD4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHvQdwGXJ1jUeQWpIDU7p30Vw-N0Q)

IsNull example:

```
Select Id, Car Plate, Username, Color, Year, IsNull(  Rent , Convert(bit, 0)) AS Rent
```

(links taken from T-SQL for SQL Server. Other database systmes may have different syntax.)

Comment: Oracle has `is null` and `is not null` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can also the example:

SELECT ISNULL(DC_Requisition.id,0) as RequisitionId,

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT Id, Car Plate, Username, Color, Year,NVL(Rent,0) FROM TABLE;
```

The NVL function uses the `Rent` value if it is present, otherwise it shows a 0.